# it's throw an exception when parsing json

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I'm programming with android studio and want to parse json with this link:
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
and put the details in a class I created that names details and have a list of them but it throws an exception. what should I do?
Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 static ArrayList<Details> details= new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new myserver2().execute((String[]) null);
    Adapter adptor=new Adapter(this,details);
    ListView l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    l.setAdapter(adptor);
    Log.i("**(*si","si");
}
private class myserver2 extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String s;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hp = new HttpGet("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        try

        {
            HttpResponse r = client.execute(hp);
            HttpEntity ent = r.getEntity();
            String s = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                Details d = null;
                obj=array.getJSONObject(i);
                d.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id")));
                d.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("userId")));
                d.setBody(obj.getString("body"));
                d.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                details.add(d);
            }

        } catch (
                IOException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (
                JSONException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Details:

```
public class Details {
int id=0,userid=0;
String body,title;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(int userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

}
and Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Details> {
Context c;
ArrayList<Details> details;
public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Details> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.item, objects);
    c=context;
    details=objects;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    TextView body= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.body);
    TextView title= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    String body2= details.get(position).getBody();
    String title2= details.get(position).getTitle();
    body.setText(body2);
    title.setText(title2);
    return v;
}
```

}

but it throws an exception that:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.etsiamak.practice5.MainActivity$myserver2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:56)
        at com.etsiamak.practice5.MainActivity$myserver2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:37)
```

int this two line:

```
 d.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id")));
```

and

```
 private class myserver2 extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
```

Comment: can you share the trace of the exception please?

Comment: @AndreuRodrígueziDonaire done!

Comment: That's all? You should debug with the info I've given you in the answer

Comment: Firstly handle all exception change } catch (
                IOException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (
                JSONException e
                )

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
TO:
catch(Exception e){

}

Comment: After that check your json data if it truly outputs a json.. do it

Comment: Clearly you are calling `Details d = null` and then `d.set..`. `d` is null at that point.

Comment: Yah true xD ahahahaha declare the d man!! d = new Details(); etc xD

Comment: @Codebender yes true thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yous should check:

`d.setId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("id")));`

- If d is null in that moment.
- If obj is null in that moment.
- If the key "id" is in the object and it's a string representing an Integer.

If you debug taking in account all of this the most probably is that you could find the error or at least give us more info about it.